# Angular.js - ngBindHtml changes between 1.2.0-RC2 and 1.2.0-RC3

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

Upon updating from angular 1.2.0-RC.2 to 1.2.0-RC.3 I noticed a breaking change triggered by changes to how ngBindHtmlDirective parses scope data (via [this change](https://github.com/chirayuk/angular.js/commit/e2068ad426075ac34c06c12e2fac5f594cc81969)). What I do is fetch a piece of SVG and then display it (SVG is valid and all that).

I have this bit of template markup:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-bind-html="svg"></div>
</div>
```

And some logic on my app that requests the SVG from the server and then assigns it to `$scope`:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', 'API', function($scope, $sce, API) {
  API.getSVG().then( function(resp) {
    $scope.svg = $sce.trustAsHtml(resp.data.svg);
  });
}]);
```

This used to work on RC2 but doesn't anymore on RC3. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a simple [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B87ca/2/) and it works fine with Angular **1.2.0-RC3** up to **1.2.4**.

**JS**

```
$scope.svg = $sce.trustAsHtml('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle r="50"/></svg>');
```